# password when try to view the source code of Form,how to delete?

Tags: ms-access

I have a problem while i have tried to open a source code view of a form in access 2003.that need from me a password but i havn't any password.how can I delete this password request?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This password will have been put in place by the application developer in order to protect the source code from view, it can be removed, however you must first enter the password, which you will need to obtain from whoever put it in place assuming they would allow you to.